# Java - Removing the double quotes in XML attributes

Tags: regex, xml, attributes, java-6, double-quotes

I have an xml string which I get via a REST call. However, some of the attributes have corrupted values. For example:

```
<property name="foo" value="Some corrupted String because of "something" like that"/>
```

How can I replace double-quotes either not preceded by **value=** or not follown by **/>** with a single quote and get a valid XML string out of that corrupted one in Java 6?

*EDIT:*

I have tried to modify this lookahead/lookbehind regex that was used for VisualBasic. But because of the incompatibility of escape characters I guess, I could not create the Java version of it. Here it is:

`(?<=^[^""]*""(?>[^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*)"(?! \s+ \w+=|\s* [/?]?" >)|(?<!\w+=)""(?=[^""]*""(?>[^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*$)`

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well, I have tried to modify this lookahead/lookbehind regex that was used for VisualBasic. But because of the incompatibility of escape characters I guess, I could not create the Java version of it. Here it is:
`(?<=^[^""]*""(?>[^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*)"(?! \s+ \w+=|\s* [/?]?" >)|(?<!\w+=)""(?=[^""]*""(?>[^""]*""[^""]*"")*[^""]*$)`

Comment: You are better off with something like [`\\s+[\\w:.-]+=\"([^\"]*(?:\"(?!\\s+[\\w:.-]+=\"|\\s*/?>)[^\"]*)*)\"`](https://regex101.com/r/cP7fD2/1) and then just replace the double quotes inside each Group 1. Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/Rx2q4H).

Comment: I tried your snippet. Yet, it needs some modification. The raw result of the REST call is like:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8**"**?>
<resources>
  <resource>    <properties>
      <property name=**"**name" value="retrieveFoo"/>
.
.`
And the result after I have applied your solution, it became: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8&quot;?>
<resources>
  <resource>    <properties>
      <property name=&quot;name" value="retrieveFoo"/>
.
.`

It works for the rest. However, the xml declaration and the very first attribute of the string are also replaced with &quot;

Comment: Ok, use `(?:\/?|\?)` instead of `/?`. I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\s+[\w:.-]+="([^"]*(?:"(?!\s+[\w:.-]+="|\s*(?:\/?|\?)>)[^"]*)*)"
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cA4rN2/1). It will match any attribute name/value pair capturing the latter into Group 1 that we can change inside a callback.

Here is a [Java code demo](http://ideone.com/td6PMV):

```
String s =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <resources> <resource> <properties> <property name=\"name\" value=\"retrieveFoo\"/>\n<property name=\"foo\" value=\"Some corrupted String because of \"something\" like that\"/>";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\s+[\\w:.-]+=\")([^\"]*(?:\"(?!\\s+[\\w:.-]+=\"|\\s*(?:/?|\\?)>)[^\"]*)*)\"").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1) + m.group(2).replace("\"", "&quot;") + "\"");
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Output:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <resources> <resource> <properties> <property name="name" value="retrieveFoo"/>
<property name="foo" value="Some corrupted String because of &quot;something&quot; like that"/>`

Comment: Converted your answer to C# for someone else (your a RegEx chief). http://stackoverflow.com/a/37177420/214898

Comment: Better use 
m.appendReplacement(result, Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group(1) + m.group(2).replace("\"", "\'") + "\""));
In case the text contains Slashes ('\') and dollar signs ('$') so they will be given no special meaning.