# Replace double quote with &quot; in XML file

Tags: java, regex, xml, saxparser

I have a XML file which contain quotes as follows

`<feast key="NAME" value="NAME TEST 'xxxxx"yyyy' $"/>`

I need to replace `xxxxx"yyyy` to `xxxxx&quot;yyyy` in all occurrence.

Note:  xxxxx and yyyy are defined by user. So it can be of any form.

Here i included the sample XML and code to parse.

**TestSaxParse.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?> 
<TEST Office="TEST Office">
    <LINE key="112313133320">
        <TESTNO value="0"/>
        <FEATURE>
            <feast key="001" value="001"/>
            <feast key="NAME" value="NAME TEST 'xxxxx_&_yyyy' $"/>
        </FEATURE>
    </LINE>
    <LINE key="112313133321">
        <TESTNO value="0"/>
        <FEATURE>
            <feast key="002" value="002"/>
            <feast key="NAME" value="NAME TEST 'xxxxx"yyyy' $"/>
        </FEATURE>
    </LINE>
</TEST>
```

**SaxParseEx.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SaxParseEx extends DefaultHandler{

    private static String xmlFilePath = "/home/system/TestSAXParse.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SaxParseEx SaxParseEx = new SaxParseEx();
        SAXParserFactory fact = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser;
        try {

            Path path = Paths.get(xmlFilePath);
            Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);

            // replace & with &amp; 
            content = content.replaceAll( "(&(?!amp;))", "&amp;");
           // content = content.replaceAll( "(\"(?!quot;))", "&quot;"); Need regex to replace " with &quot; only on specific place where i mentioned above

            // Write updated content to XML file
            Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));

            // XML Parsing
            parser = fact.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(new File(xmlFilePath), SaxParseEx);
            System.out.println("PARSE SUCCESS");
            return;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("PARSE FAILED");
    }
}
```

**O/P**

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/system/TestSAXParse.xml; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 46; Element type "feast" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

I have replace all `&` with `&amp;` to fix the SAXParseException on Line No. 7. I cannot replace `"` with `&quot;`

**EDIT:**

I cannot use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744460/java-removing-the-double-quotes-in-xml-attributes). I'm looking for different solution because of

1. The XML file is large size ( > 100MB)
2. So i think it is not feasible to compile and replace every line within double quote values as suggested in the answer.
3. I'm looking for replace all as like

`content = content.replaceAll( "(&(?!amp;))", "&amp;");`

Is there any possibility to write a regex like that?

Comment: The `&` before `gt;` and `lt;` should not be replaced either, I think. It must be `content.replaceAll( "&(?!amp;|[gl]t;)", "&amp;");`

Comment: as your xml is invalid to begin with it logically can´t be parsed. The problem here is that the `'xxxxx"` ends the xml tag and you get a parsing error.

Comment: check the following threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744460/java-removing-the-double-quotes-in-xml-attributes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176682/replace-double-quotes-within-attributes-only-in-xml-c-sharp

Comment: Just worked out another regex that can help with the code in the linked question (to be modified a bit): [`="(.*?)"(?=\s+[\w:-]+="|\s*\/?>)`](https://regex101.com/r/mX5pJ7/1). However, that solution should be working.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : Please see my updated question.

Comment: If `content = content.replaceAll( "(&(?!amp;))", "&amp;");` will work for you, the `StringBuffer` based solution will also work. Have at least tried?

Comment: you should write shell script to use regex to do string replacement line by line... 100MB is not problem at all if you do it line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all `"` with `&quot;` when it is enclosed with `'`. So i added below lines before to `Files.write`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*[\"].*)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
while (matcher.find()) {
    content = content.replaceAll(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(1).replace("\"", "&quot;"));
}
```